# Android: How to raise volume above safe level pragmatically

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

How can increase volume above safe level when headset connected, trying out this d't work, stop at safe level.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of using the `ADJUST_RAISE` constant value, you use a variable like 20?

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
```

Try if that works.

Comment: I tried with constant values, It's not worked, Ronny Thankyou.